# Differenza tra sfrontatezza e sfacciatezza?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, single-words

C'è per caso una differenza tra essere sfrontati ed essere sfacciati?

Comment: sfacciataggine credo sia più comunque di sfacciatezza, che non ho mai sentito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sono sinonimi, anche come aggettivi (sfacciato o sfrontato). Sfacciatezza è un termine meno comune.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sfrontatezza%2Csfacciatezza%2Csfacciato%2C%20sfrontato&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csfrontatezza%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csfacciatezza%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csfacciato%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csfrontato%3B%2Cc0) mostra un minor uso di *sfacciatezza*, mentre gli altri termini sono molto più comuni.

Nel linguaggio comune direi che sono entrambi usati senza particolari distinzioni.